Why EF Core LINQ query works okay for one child and does not work for another one?
So I have a query to get a list of chats with 2 users (including their pictures) and the last message.
An exception is thrown because of that last message sub-query:

"The LINQ expression 'ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p5.P2pChatId
ORDER BY p5.CreatedOn DESC)' could not be translated. Either rewrite
the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client
evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable',
'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information."

LastMessage = x.P2pChatMessages
             .OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedOn)
             .Select(y => new P2pChatMessageViewModel()
             {
                 Id = y.Id,
                 ChatId = y.P2pChatId,
                 UserId = y.UserId,
                 CreatedOn = y.CreatedOn.ToString("s") + "+00:00",
                 Text = y.Text,
             })
             .FirstOrDefault()

My question is why this sub-query fails, while the same sub-query right above passes ok:
Person2 = x.Person2 == null ? null : new UserViewModel()
             {
                 Id = x.Person2.Id,
                 Username = x.Person2.UserName,
                 Email = x.Person2.Email,
                 ProfilePicture = new ImageViewModel()
                 {
                     UserId = x.Person2.Id,
                     Url = x.Person2.ProfilePictures.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedOn).Select(y => y.Image.Url).FirstOrDefault(),
                     Id = x.Person2.ProfilePictures.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedOn).Select(y => y.Image.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
                 },
             },

Full query:
 var list = await _db.P2pChats
     .OrderByDescending(x => x.P2pChatMessages.Any(y => !y.IsRead))
     .Select(x => new P2pChatViewModel
     {
         Id = x.Id,
         Person1 = x.Person1 == null ? null : new UserViewModel()
         {
             Id = x.Person1.Id,
             Username = x.Person1.UserName,
             Email = x.Person1.Email,
             ProfilePicture = new ImageViewModel()
             {
                 UserId = x.Person1.Id,
                 Url = x.Person1.ProfilePictures.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedOn).Select(y => y.Image.Url).FirstOrDefault(),
                 Id = x.Person1.ProfilePictures.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedOn).Select(y => y.Image.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
             },
         },
         Person2 = x.Person2 == null ? null : new UserViewModel()
         {
             Id = x.Person2.Id,
             Username = x.Person2.UserName,
             Email = x.Person2.Email,
             ProfilePicture = new ImageViewModel()
             {
                 UserId = x.Person2.Id,
                 Url = x.Person2.ProfilePictures.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedOn).Select(y => y.Image.Url).FirstOrDefault(),
                 Id = x.Person2.ProfilePictures.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedOn).Select(y => y.Image.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
             },
         },
         LastMessage = x.P2pChatMessages
             .OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedOn)
             .Select(y => new P2pChatMessageViewModel()
                 {
                     Id = y.Id,
                     ChatId = y.P2pChatId,
                     UserId = y.UserId,
                     CreatedOn = y.CreatedOn.ToString("s") + "+00:00",
                     Text = y.Text,
                 })
             .FirstOrDefault()
         })
     .Take(50)
     .ToListAsync();


In your case, client-side evaluation does not mean fetching lots of rows you didn't mean to fetch otherwise. Hence, it won't be a massive drawback if you go for the client-side evaluation.

@ShahryarSaljoughi I did client side evaluation. But I also want to understand why that is happening. Perhaps, I have a gap in ef core and linq understanding.

They are struggling with the null check like x.Person2 == null ? null : new ... in the projection (select). They somehow handle it for navigation properties when returned directly, but not for nested projection like this. I don't think this has been fixed even in the most recent EFC.

Try remove .ToString("s") + "+00:00", it is non-translatable.

The problem is that you have a client-side evaluation in CreatedOn, and this is being placed before the ROW_NUMBER transform.
You can solve this by either changing to a server-side evaluation. For this you would need to add the CONVERT function to your model as a DbFunction, then call it:
CreatedOn = MyFunctions.Convert(y.CreatedOn, 126) + "+00:00",

Or push the row-number to earlier in the query before client-side evaluation, by using an intermediate variable
var list = await _db.P2pChats
     .OrderByDescending(x => x.P2pChatMessages.Any(y => !y.IsRead))
     .Select(x => new {
         x,
         LastMessage = x.P2pChatMessages.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedOn).FirstOrDefault()
     })
     .Select(x => new P2pChatViewModel
     {
         Id = x.x.Id,
         Person1 = x.x.Person1 == null ? null : new UserViewModel()
         {
             Id = x.x.Person1.Id,
             Username = x.x.Person1.UserName,
             Email = x.x.Person1.Email,
             ProfilePicture = new ImageViewModel()
             {
                 UserId = x.x.Person1.Id,
                 Url = x.x.Person1.ProfilePictures.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedOn).Select(y => y.Image.Url).FirstOrDefault(),
                 Id = x.x.Person1.ProfilePictures.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedOn).Select(y => y.Image.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
             },
         },
         Person2 = x.x.Person2 == null ? null : new UserViewModel()
         {
             Id = x.x.Person2.Id,
             Username = x.x.Person2.UserName,
             Email = x.x.Person2.Email,
             ProfilePicture = new ImageViewModel()
             {
                 UserId = x.x.Person2.Id,
                 Url = x.x.Person2.ProfilePictures.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedOn).Select(y => y.x.Image.Url).FirstOrDefault(),
                 Id = x.x.Person2.ProfilePictures.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedOn).Select(y => y.Image.Id).FirstOrDefault(),
             },
         },
         LastMessage = new P2pChatMessageViewModel
         {
             Id = x.LastMessage.Id,
             ChatId = x.LastMessage.P2pChatId,
             UserId = x.LastMessage.UserId,
             CreatedOn = x.LastMessage.CreatedOn.ToString("s") + "+00:00",
             Text = x.LastMessage.Text,
          })
     })
     .Take(50)
     .ToListAsync();


However, I strongly suspect that this query can be written much better anyway, by combining and moving the duplicate subqueries into variables. This is often easier in Query Syntax rather than Method Syntax, because you can use let.
var list = await
    from c in _db.P2pChats
    let cm = c.P2pChatMessages
        .GroupBy(c => 1)  // group by empty set
        .Select(g => new {
            AnyUnread = g.Where(y => !y.IsRead).Any(),
            LastMessage = g.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedOn).FirstOrDefault(),
        })
    let ppImage1 = c.Person1?.ProfilePictures.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedOn).Select(y => y.Image).FirstOrDefault()
    let ppImage2 = c.Person2?.ProfilePictures.OrderByDescending(y => y.CreatedOn).Select(y => y.Image).FirstOrDefault()
    orderby cm.AnyUnread descending
    select new P2pChatViewModel
    {
        Id = c.Id,
        Person1 = c.Person1 == null ? null : new UserViewModel()
        {
            Id = c.Person1.Id,
            Username = c.Person1.UserName,
            Email = c.Person1.Email,
            ProfilePicture = new ImageViewModel()
            {
                UserId = c.Person1.Id,
                Url = ppImage1.Url,
                Id = ppImage1.Id,
            },
        },
        Person2 = c.Person2 == null ? null : new UserViewModel()
        {
            Id = c.Person2.Id,
            Username = c.Person2.UserName,
            Email = c.Person2.Email,
            ProfilePicture = new ImageViewModel()
            {
                UserId = c.Person2.Id,
                Url = ppImage2.Url,
                Id = ppImage2.Id,
            },
        },
        LastMessage = cm.LastMessage,
     .Take(50)
     .ToListAsync();


I'm really curious about the better approach and would like to learn from it. Could you provide any more performant query?

What exactly do you want to know? I thought it was fairly clear.
